# How to handle big lists on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have this xaml:

```
    <controls:Pivot>
        <controls:PivotItem Header="All Stations">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <ItemsControl x:Name="allStations">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                                    Click="OnStationClick" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
```

And in the code behind I set `allStations.ItemsSource` to a collection with roughly 2500 items, which makes the UI freeze for a few seconds. What can I do speed up this load? The virtualization should ensure it would only need to create the controls for 10 or so items, but it seems it's creating controls for all items.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bind to the huge 2500 items collection. Copy first 50-100 items to observable collection and bind that to *allStations*. Then simply [detect when the user scrolled to the bottom of the list](http://blog.slimcode.com/2010/09/11/detect-when-a-listbox-scrolls-to-its-end-wp7/) and copy the next 50-100 items to the observable collection.